# How to normalize a table with multiple cells that have multiple values?

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

So I'm doing a task where I take a massive list (30,000+) of movies on Wikipedia that have multiple columns (such as the films name, the genre, the cast, the plot etc.) and upload it into Elasticsearch. However, after doing that I now want to make it so the table is in at least 1NF. I'm not really experienced in database design and the last time I did anything with Normal Form was a few years ago. So I'm looking at this table and thinking, how could I put this into 1NF. It's easy if for example there's only 1 column that has multiple values, but what do you do when there are multiple columns with multiple values as seen below.

| Film Name | Director | Cast | Genre | Wiki Page | Plot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chimmie Fadden Out West | Cecil B. DeMile | Victor Moore | Comedy, Western | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimme_Fadden_Out_West | Chimmie is sent out west... |
| 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea | Stuart Paton | Lois Alexander, Curtis Benton, Wallace Clarke, Allen Holubar | Action, Adventure | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1916_film) | A strange... |
| The Cat and the Canary | Paul Leni | Laura La Plante, Forrest Stanley, Creighton Hale | Comedy, Horror, Mystery | [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_and_the_Canary_(1927_film)|](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_and_the_Canary_(1927_film)%7C) In a... |  |

Would you just have to do something like this...

| Film Name | Director | Cast | Genre | Wiki Page | Plot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chimmie Fadden Out West | Cecil B. DeMile | Victor Moore | Comedy | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimme_Fadden_Out_West | Chimmie is sent out west... |
| Chimmie Fadden Out West | Cecil B. DeMile | Victor Moore | Western | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimme_Fadden_Out_West | Chimmie is sent out west... |
| 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea | Stuart Paton | Lois Alexander | Action | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1916_film) | A strange... |
| 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea | Stuart Paton | Lois Alexander | Adventure | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1916_film) | A strange... |
| 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea | Stuart Paton | Curtis Benton | Action | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1916_film) | A strange... |
| 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea | Stuart Paton | Curtis Benton | Adventure | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1916_film) | A strange... |
| 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea | Stuart Paton | Wallace Clarke | Adventure | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1916_film) | A strange... |
| 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea | Stuart Paton | Wallace Clarke | Action | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1916_film) | A strange... |

etc? I'm surely missing something extremely simple when it comes to converting a table with multiple cells with multiple values into 1NF, but I'm not sure what.

Thanks.

Comment: You're just asking for a textbook. Follow one. However- ["1NF" has many meanings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) All involve replacing some table with parameterized structure by some table(s) with a column per parameter. So you need to tell us what you mean when you use "1NF". Preferably also textbook name & edition. 
So how are you stuck getting there, and if you're "not sure", exactly how are you stuck in what process? Also, starting from such a "universal relation" and normalizing it is not a good way to design a DB. Again, a textbook.

Comment: @philipxy I was searching for the answer to my question for a couple of hours before I asked here. The definition of 1NF I'm using is: All the columns in a table should have unique names and Only 1 value per cell. For example 1 Director name, or 1 plot description. The problem I'm having is every example I find in books/websites have a table with like 4 columns, and 3 of the 4 columns only contain single values and then 1 column will have 2 or 3 values. That's easy to convert to 1NF, but I'm not sure how to convert a table with like 4 columns that all have multiple values in a single cell.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Again, you're just asking us to rewrite a textbook. Your "1NF" description is not helpful; a relation has only one value per cell, so by that definition your original relation is already in 1NF. Also eliminating duplicate column names is not part of anybody's definition of a "1NF". You seem confused re non-relations vs relations, before even getting to making a relation "1NF". Follow & quote a particular published textbook so we can fix the meanings of terms. Ask re where 1st stuck. All of this is explained in the chain of links from my 1st comment.

Comment: If your storage engine of choice is Elasticsearch, why are you concerned about normalisation at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's actually pretty easy to **normalize** when there's multiple fields, some with varying amounts of data points in a single field of the same row. Just follow this rule: Any column that has multiple data points within the column of the same row should become it's own table. So in your example that could be `Cast` and `Genre`. It's immediately apparent that those two columns represent a many-to-many relationship because of the very fact that there's multiple values stored in a single column of the same row.

As nbk mentions, you'll need a **linking / bridge table** to store that many-to-many relationship. So while your new `Cast` table may have columns like `CastId` (primary key), `FirstName`, and `LastName`, your **linking table** between `Cast` and `Film` would be named something like `FilmCast` and have the field `FilmId` (from your `Film` table) with a foreign key reference, and it would also have the `CastId` with a foreign key reference to the `Cast` table. Then every row in that `FilmCast` **linking table** would represent a specific single `Cast` person for a single specific `Film`.

You would repeat this same ideology for each other column in your `Films` table with multiple data points per row. Once you have the appropriate tables for each normalized column then you have no need to store that data in the main `Film` table anymore and could remove those columns from it.

Answer (score 2):

Normalisation is to remove information from tables, that are repe4ated by many times and ids as int are smaller than any text.

The bridge Tables you need, because you have a m:n relationship between film and users(cast, director, musician...)

Occupation is in my opionion a attributs of the relationship between film and user

```
Film (idfilm,Titel, plot,Wiki_Page, year,... )

Film2user (idfilm,iduser,idtype)

type  (idtype,occupation)

user (iduser, Name, Birth,...)

genre (idgenre,name)

Film2genre(idfilm, idgenre)
```

as you develop further, you can add more attributes or tables if you find more such redundant information